# How to install 64-bit Tor Browser on Windows 10

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, windows

I've downloaded the Windows Tor Browser package from [here](https://www.torproject.org/download/download.html.en).  I installed the Tor Browser on Windows 10 64-bit.  Task Manager shows Tor Browser, tor.exe running as 32 bit processes.   The installation process didn't allow me to select 32 or 64 bit.   Can Tor Browser run as a 64-bit process on Windows?  If so, what must I do to make that happen?  My machine has 8GB RAM and I want Tor Browser to have access to 8GB instead of 4GB for 32-bit processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tor Browser is currently only distributed as a 32bit program for Windows. This is quite common for Windows applications, which natively supports 32bit applications on its 64bit operating system.

Mozilla only started publishing [64bit Firefox for Windows in late 2015](https://blog.mozilla.org/futurereleases/2015/12/15/firefox-64-bit-for-windows-available/) and the Tor Browser team didn't consider the code base stable enough to be a candidate [until recently](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/20636).

It's not currently available but it's likely that they will eventually be introduced.