# Install of 64Bit-Version

Tags: configuration

The Installer
automatically installs the 32Bit Version on my 64Bit Windows10 PC.

How can I install
the 64Bit Version?

Answer (score 0):

Tor is only distributed as a 32 bit application.

Credit to [canonizing ironize](https://tor.stackexchange.com/users/12737/canonizing-ironize) for answering this [question](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/14591/how-to-install-64-bit-tor-browser-on-windows-10).

> Tor Browser is currently only distributed as a 32bit program for
>   Windows. This is quite common for Windows applications, which natively
>   supports 32bit applications on its 64bit operating system.
>
> Mozilla only started publishing [64bit Firefox for Windows in late
>   2015](https://blog.mozilla.org/futurereleases/2015/12/15/firefox-64-bit-for-windows-available/)
>   and the Tor Browser team didn't consider the code base stable enough
>   to be a candidate [until
>   recently](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/20636).
>
> It's not currently available but it's likely that they will eventually
>   be introduced.